# Rails Foundation 5 datetimepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, datetimepicker

I keep getting an error while using DateTimepicker gem `'foundation-datetimepicker-rails'`

The error I keep getting is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fdatepicker'
```

The html looks like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :due_date_proposed, id: "dp1", value: "31.01.2014" %>
```

Before the `</body>` tag, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#dp1').fdatepicker();
</script>
```

Can anyone help, please?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you added the library to your **application.js**?

Comment: Yes, I have both `//= require foundation-datetimepicker` and `@import 'foundation-datetimepicker';` in _foundation_and_overrides.scss_

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` after adding the gem in your _gemfile_?

Answer (score 0):

I followed with original documentation https://github.com/najlepsiwebdesigner/foundation-datepicker 
and copied js and css files in vendor 
Everything works: 
Librariries in gem are broken. (same error) 
My diff with fdatepicker initialization: 
https://github.com/itsNikolay/fdatepicker/commit/286b9a38dba9fdedda9751d838bb9d6d4c5336c7 
Got http://screencloud.net/v/cOyh

Comment: `value: "02-16-2012"` could you replace value on this ?

Comment: Yes, the field is writable.

Comment: Write please which ruby and rails versions you use, i'll help you a little later.

Comment: ruby 1.9.3, rails 4.0.0. Thanks!

Comment: I've inverstigated the problem and edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to show a DatePicker or a DateTimePicker? 
Try to initialize it like this:

```
$('#dp1').fdatetimepicker();
```